# Get variable from url in view

Tags: python, http, flask

I want to make an HTTP GET request to `ip:port/this1234` and use "1234" as a variable in Python code.  The "1234" is an arbitrary int.  How do I get the int as an argument to my view?

```
@app.route('/stop####')
    def stop####():
        global stopped
            if stopped:
               call(["./stop.sh"], shell = True)
            stopped = False
        return "started"
    return "already started"
```

Comment: I don't think this user deserves a downvote as he is obviously looking at some form of documentation and merely having trouble determining how to split up the part of the URI which is his input variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to take a look at the [Quickstart guide](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/).

Meanwhile, you can get POST data using

```
myvar =  request.form["myvar"]
```

and GET using

```
myvar = request.args.get("myvar")
```

The guide then goes on to mention some error handling recommendations and references the more in depth [request object page](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.request).

> We recommend accessing URL parameters with get or by catching the KeyError because users might change the URL and presenting them a 400 bad request page in that case is not user friendly.
>
> For a full list of methods and attributes of the request object, head
>   over to the request documentation.

You might also want to look at [routing](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/routing/#) a bit. I'm uncertain what you're trying to accomplish with the pound sign in your routing (EDIT: I see what you mean on re-reading; see edit at bottom). Note the quote below from a [comment](http://community.sitepoint.com/t/a-pound-sign-in-an-url-for-passing-data/6979/2) on SitePoint.

> browsers don't send the `#whatever` part of the URL to the server in the HTTP request when requesting the page

Ok, so if you want to pass the value in the URI, I recommend something more like: `example.com/this/1234` and your routing rule would look like `@app.route('/this/<myVar>')` above your `def my_func(myVar):`

Finally, at some level, killing any process based off of an http request seems awful daring, but you know your environment best, and for all I know, it might not even be exposed to the internet. Goodluck, and don't forget to be safe about this.

Comment: @app.route('/kill/<pid>')
    def getkillid(pid):
        return 'pid = %s' % pid


so by my knowlage so far that will work ?

Comment: In your example, if someone navigated to example.com/kill/123, your flask app would then return a response object of 'pid = 123' as the body and the default http header (200 response code, which means success).

Answer (score 0):

I think the obvious way to do it would be:

```
@app.route('/kill/<int:pid>')
def kill(pid):
    .....
```